# iis return response with error Code 404 in File Uploading to web Api Server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, iis, webapi

I have a website that implemented with .net core 2.1 and angular js.
I published this website on windows server that is running on  IIS.
The problem is iis return response with error Code 404 to my requests on some files (like js files or html) but there are the files and when I refresh my website it loads correctly.

Also I enabled a log on my IIS based on this solution :
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules.](https://stackoverflow.com)
and it is my log result :
[https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ilxl6y6ep4nmd6t/AAA-3PqVy55ODzr2tVEYPyUQa?dl=0](https://stackoverflow.com)
It is very confusing that there is the file but iis return 404.

Comment: How many web servers you have ? And could you share the web.config file or rewrite code for us.

Comment: After my further investigation, I found this example `https://tempwebsite:443/ClientApp/Waste/dust/destructionRequest/destructionRequestController.js`, usually our SPA projects or angular projects need to be compiled before publishing, will be published under the wwwroot folder. Your path should not be a static resource, are you sure you need to access this file?